# Dropdown/Radio Inputs for Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I currently have an Input model which contains two attributes.

- Path **- of type CharField**
- File **- of type FileField**

When creating an Input object via CreateView, the user may only choose one or the other. How will I write my code to allow them to choose either and show the input form for either attribute.
e.g choosing File will show a FileFile input and vice versa.

I was thinking of using either a dropdown or a radio button.